# iterating javascript object in jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug, sails.js

I'm sending a view via my controller in sails.js that has layout parameters i.e. title and users:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    User.find().done(function(err, users) {
      res.view('home/index', { 
        title: 'Tester',
        users: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users))
      });
    });
  }
};
```

This code finds all of the users (only 1 as of now) and i'm sending the view with the users as JSON.  I'm trying to iterate over the JSON and print each user email, name, and id.

```
extends ../layout

block body
  ul
    each user in users
      li= user.email
```

This is the data returned:

```
[ { email: 'myemail@google.me',
    name: 'MyNameFull',
    id: 1,
    createdAt: '2014-05-17T03:41:16.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2014-05-17T03:41:16.000Z' } ]
```

And i'm getting this error on line 5 (`each user in users`):

```
3| block body\n    4| \tul\n  > 5| \t\teach user in users\n    6| \t\t\tli= user.email\n\nCannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

In my `config/routes.js` file I had this code:

```
'/': {
  view: 'home/index'
}
```

Changed it to:

```
'get /': 'UserController'
```

It wasn't pointing to the proper controller...